# Sql Inner Join among 2 tables summing the qty field multiple times

Tags: sql

I have two tables , A and B

Table A contains:

```
OrderNo |  StyleNo     |  Qty  
O-20    | S-15         |  20  
O-20    | S-18         |  40
O-25    | S-19         |  50
```

Table B contains:

```
OrderNo |  StyleNo     | Ship Qty  
O-20    | S-15         |   5  
O-20    | S-18         |  30  
O-20    | S-15         |  12  
O-20    | S-18         |  6
```

Result Requires

```
OrderNo |  StyleNo     | Qty     | Ship Qty      
O-20    | S-15         |   20    |  17  
O-20    | S-18         |   40    |  36  
O-25    | S-19         |   50    |  0
```

The following query is not working

```
select   
    B.Orderno, B.StyleNo, sum(A.Qty), sum(B.QtyShip) 
from     
    A 
inner join 
    B on A.OrderNo = B.OrderNo and A.StyleNo = B.StyleNo 
group by 
    B.OrderNo, B.StyleNo
```

Comment: Well what did you want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is that it's summing the qty field multiple times.  Move the sums to subqueries and use a join on those:

```
select a.orderno, a.styleno, a.qty, b.qtyship
from (
  select orderno, styleno, sum(qty) qty
  from a
  group by orderno, styleno
  ) a
    join (
  select orderno, styleno, sum(qtyship) qtyship
  from b
  group by orderno, styleno
  ) b on a.orderno = b.orderno and a.styleno = b.styleno
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb78b/2)